# prevent css :hover on an element

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have this HTML:

```
<div class="SomeClass">test</div>
<div class="SomeClass" id="SomeID">test</div>
<div class="SomeClass">test</div>
```

with this CSS

```css
.SomeClass{color:blue;}
.SomeClass:hover{color:red}
```

I want the hover effect not to apply to the `SomeID` div. I can do this with jQuery but I was wondering if there's an easier way to do it with just CSS.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Would `.SomeClass, #SomeID:hover {color:blue;}` be considered as an easier way? ) Should do the trick by specificity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS is parsed in order, meaning that if after you define

```css
.SomeClass:hover { color: red; }
```

You then define a rule

```css
#SomeId.SomeClass:hover { color: blue; }
```

That should 'overwrite' the initial `color: red;`

Comment: `#SomeId.SomeClass` notation is a bit redundant, I think: `id` is applied to a single element by definition. And because of specificity its rules will override the class' ones.

Comment: It may be redundant, but it sure helps with readability and understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Just assign another rule to the div with an id of SomeID. This will override the other rule.

```css
.SomeClass{color:blue;}
.SomeClass:hover{color:red}
#SomeID:hover{color:blue}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ttvNw/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite the style:

```css
#SomeID:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```css
.SomeClass:not(#SomeID):hover {
    color:red;
}
```

Then it is easier to change it, but less browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at link pseudo-class specificity:

Remember: **LAHV** (`:link`, `:active`, `:hover`, `:visited`).

First, in order to cascade properly, let's assign the following to `.SomeClass`:

```css
.SomeClass:link, .SomeClass:active, .SomeClass:visited { color: blue; }
.SomeClass:hover { color: red; }
```

Next, let's specify `#SomeID`:

```css
#SomeID:hover { color: blue; }
```

`id` always takes precedence over `class`.